# Unlink xcode account from expired developer account

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-developer

For the past several years I have maintained an Apple Developer account so I could dabble in iOS programming. I have never published an app. My account recently expired and I don't wish to renew it. But I still want to write some apps for my own iPad. I understand this is now possible but my apple id is tied to my developer account and I don't know how to break the connection so I can set a free account.

Answer (score 0):

You can add and remove Apple IDs from Xcode -> Preferences (cmd-,) -> Accounts. Xcode supports multiple accounts at once, as well.